# Does this objective-c code cause memory leak?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

Compare the following 2 snippets:

sample 1:

```
[[UIApplication shareApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"]]
```

and sample 2:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSUrl URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"];
[[UIApplication shareApplication] openURL: url];
[url release];
```

Does sample 1 cause memory leak?
is [url release] in sample 2 redundant?

If memory leak does happen, how bad is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sample 1 does not cause a memory leak and is the general way to do it. The `NSURL` object is autoreleased, and thus you're not supposed to release it yourself (as you do in sample 2).

Answer (score 2):

Sample 1 is perfectly fine, as was already described above. However, sample 2 should actually result in a crash. `-URLWithString:` is autoreleased, so its retain count is effectively already going to be zero when the next autorelease pool is drained. Releasing it explicitly like you're doing will bring its retain count to 0 immediately, resulting in deallocation. Then, when the autorelease pool is drained, it'll try to release that string again, resulting in a crash.

It's always best to use the Build and Analyze command in Xcode. It can pick up and warn you about almost all memory leak issues, although it's not perfect. Still, it's a good practice.

Answer (score -2):

@BoltClock, I think you are not entirely correct in saying that the object is autoreleased in sample 1.

In sample 2, a variable named `url` is assigned the object returned from the `[NSUrl URLWithString:]` method, thus incrementing its retain count by 1. To balance that, we need to `release` it. While in sample 1, the reference to the object is directly passed to the receiver and we have nothing to worry about its retain count, hence no release.

Note that we are not autoreleasing, since we have not retained anything in the first place. "There is no variable in the code that is being autoreleased!"

Please correct me if I am conceptually wrong somewhere. And just to complete this, there is no leak in either of the samples and both are correct ways of doing this.

Comment: I am sorry, but this is wrong. You should not release an object unless you created it using a method that begins with "alloc" or "new" or a method that contains "copy". URLWithString: returns an autoreleased NSURL, which will automatically be deallocated at the end of the runloop. [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)

Comment: Agreed with the first part. And if URLWithString returns an autoreleased object, then the `[url release]` in sample 2 IS redundant, right?

Comment: You are wrong. The object is autoreleased by NSURL class. When you call +(NSURL *)URLWithString:(NSString *)string the NSURL class allocs-init a new instance, then autorelease and returns it to you. If you don't retain it you are not guaranteed it will not be released during the app life (it will be probably released during the next run loop). If NSURL were not releasing the instance, you would generate a leak as by convention you are the object owner only if its "constructor" method begins with "init" or "copy".

Comment: Ohh, sorry. Now I read it and it makes sense, the previous post. I misunderstood BoltClock's post. He is correct.

Comment: Quite misleading!  Assigning an object to a variable does not affect a retain count in any way.  Only calling a method, such as the getter/setter of a property, can do memory management.  Without any dot or brackets, there is no method call.

Comment: You **never** affect a retain count unless you do `retain` (`copy` doesn't even increase the retain count of the same object, it makes a brand new object instead). The second way is incorrect; if you `release` an autoreleased object you get a crash because you didn't retain it for yourself.

Comment: technically, an object with an immutable state *could* `return [self retain];` in its implementation of `copyWithZone:`.